# Firefox doesnt show svg sprite

Tags: firefox, svg

Any solution, why IE and Chrome will be show my svg-sprite, but Firefox prefers to show nothing. There will be the place for the icon and on source code it will be showen, but it seems that firefox doesnt render it.

I include the svg and call the icom by this way

```
<svg class="icon icon-spoon-knife" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <use xlink:href="/adminCSS/pic/sprite.svg#icon-spoon-knife">
</svg>
```

Again, chrome and IE show it, firefox wont...

Hope you can help!

Thank you

Comment: please create a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a width and height to your svg tag or CSS.  I believe Firefox's table-cell sizing algorithm sets it to 0px × 0px if it's not declared.

```
<svg class="icon icon-spoon-knife" width="16px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
```

Comment: Thank you, but nothing happens. In the css-sheet i placed height and width, if i change its values, the place for icon will in- or decrease, but icon is still invisible...